# How to make JavaScript else if statements less messy?

Tags: javascript

How can I make the following else if statements less messy?

```
var visas = ["Blue-Collar Worker", "Business", "Foreign Student", "Internship", "Investment", "Joining Foreign Family", "Joining Minors", "Joining Taiwanese Family", "Studying Mandarin Chinese", "Tourism", "Visa-Exempt Entry", "Visiting Family", "Religious Work", "White-Collar Worker"];

var visaOld = $('#inputVisaOld').val(); var visaNew = $('#inputVisaNew').val();

if (visaOld === 'Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew === 'Foreign Student') {
  return '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for FR -> FS</div>'; 
} else if (visaOld === 'Visa-Exempt Entry' && visaNew === 'White-Collar Worker') {
  return '<div class="alert alert-info"><a class="alert-link">Visitor Visa for Employment Purpose</a></div>'; 
} else if (visaOld === 'Tourism' && visaNew === 'Joining Taiwanese Family') {
  return '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for P -> TS</div>'; 
} else {
  return '<div class="alert alert-danger">Not allowed to change</div>'; 
}
```

I thought about turning it into `switch` statements but I need to declare statements in each block and I think that's not possible with `switch`?

Comment: Consider `Object {Object {String}}` then `obj[visaOld][visaNew]; // <div ...>`

Comment: Since each *if* has a return statement, there is no need for *else*.

Comment: @Paul S. you meant `visas = { visaOld: {...}, visaNew: {...} }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might prefer using a `switch(true)` construct:

```
switch (true) {
  case (visaOld === 'Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew === 'Foreign Student'):
    return '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for FR -> FS</div>';
    break;
  case (visaOld === 'Visa-Exempt Entry' && visaNew === 'White-Collar Worker'):
    return '<div class="alert alert-info"><a class="alert-link">Visitor Visa for Employment Purpose</a></div>';
    break;
  case (visaOld === 'Tourism' && visaNew === 'Joining Taiwanese Family'):
    return '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for P -> TS</div>';
    break;
  default:
    return '<div class="alert alert-danger">Not allowed to change</div>';
    break;
}
```

Comment: I think I saw this using `false` once. What's the difference?

Comment: It's the same idea but the statement will return from whichever case evaluates to false rather than true.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit neater

```
var myString = '<div class="alert alert-info">';
var visaOld = $('#inputVisaOld').val(); var visaNew = $('#inputVisaNew').val();
if (visaOld === 'Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew === 'Foreign Student') {
  myString += 'Documents for FR -> FS'; 
} else if (visaOld === 'Visa-Exempt Entry' && visaNew === 'White-Collar Worker') {
  myString += 'Visitor Visa for Employment Purpose'; 
} else if (visaOld === 'Tourism' && visaNew === 'Joining Taiwanese Family') {
  myString += 'Documents for P -> TS'; 
} else {
  myString += 'Not allowed to change'; 
}
myString += '</div>';
return myString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use javascript's object lookup.  Not appropriate for all cases, but if you need fast lookup in a large table, this method will be faster than a long structure of if/else-if blocks or a switch, because it's a hash table lookup.

```
// setup a table
var changes = {};
changes[['Studying Mandarin Chinese', 'Foreign Student']] =
    '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for FR -> FS</div>';
changes[['Visa-Exempt Entry', 'White-Collar Worker']] =
    '<div class="alert alert-info"><a class="alert-link">Visitor Visa for Employment Purpose</a></div>';
changes[['Tourism', 'Joining Taiwanese Family']] =
    '<div class="alert alert-info">Documents for P -> TS</div>';

// do the lookup
return changes[[visaOld, visaNew]] ||
    '<div class="alert alert-danger">Not allowed to change</div>';
```